# ¿Se puede detectar grupos con caracteres en cualquier posición con Regex?

Tags: .net, regex

Estoy haciendo un verificador de password que al menos tenga una letra Mayúscula, un número, y un carácter y que sea por lo menos de 5 a 10 caracteres. La cosa es que cuando el usuario ingresa una contraseña inválida le diga al usuario qué le falta.

He intentado esto de Regex:

```
@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[&+@$#%!¡¿?])[a-zA-z0-9&+@$#%!¡¿?]{5,10}$"
```

pero este patrón detecta toda de una.

Lo que quiero es detectar grupos por separado. Por ejemplo que me detecte si tiene letras, entonces le pondré el mensaje al usuario que le faltan mayúsculas, números y signos.

Comment: ¿Has intentado separar la regex en cuatro y evaluar una por una?

Comment: Como requiere el mensaje personalizado según la regla que infrinja la cadena que requiere evaluar, tiene que utilizar una expresion regular por cada regla que desee evaluar. De esta manera, al saber con cual no hace match, sabe cual mensaje mostrar

Comment: Sale mucho más fácil, rápido y **mantenible** evaluar cada cosa por separado.

Answer (score 0):

Sería bastante más práctico revisar cada una de las condiciones por separado.

Sin embargo, si estamos con ganas de entreverar el código, podemos hacer que cada una de las partes sea un grupo opcional... Encerrando con `(...)?`.

```
@"^(?=(.*[a-z])?)(?=(.*[0-9])?)(?=(.*[&+@$#%!¡¿?])?)([a-zA-z0-9&+@$#%!¡¿?]{5,10}$)?"
```

Este regex va a coincidir *siempre*, pero intenta capturar los 4 grupos. Si alguno (o más de uno) de los grupos no se obtienen en el resultado, significa que no se cumplió esa condición.